# SQL update row while row[val]<$_POST['$val];

Tags: php, mysql

So i would like to update row only when few condition were meet.

### 1. if i already have a value for specific row

```
$val = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['$result']);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_video WHERE video_id = '$id' AND user_uid = '".$_SESSION['u_uid'] ."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($resultCheck>0){
```

so if i already have that one i don't need to insert new value, just would like to UPDATE value.

### 2. if saved value is smaller than POST value

```
if ($row['done']< $val) {
    $sql = "UPDATE user_video SET obejrzane='$val' WHERE video_id = '$id' AND user_uid='".$_SESSION['u_uid'] ."'";
    mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
```

My code working fine when i would like to insert new data. But when i would like to update, updates every time even when $_POST['$val'] is smaller than existing one in a row...  any help with be appropriate?!

## Full code

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'db.php';
$val = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['$result']);
$time = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
$id = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['$title']);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM user_video WHERE video_id = '$id' AND user_uid = '".$_SESSION['u_uid'] ."'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
$resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($resultCheck>0){
    if ($row['done']< $val) {
        $sql = "UPDATE user_video SET obejrzane='$val' WHERE video_id = '$id' AND user_uid='".$_SESSION['u_uid'] ."'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }
    echo $resultCheck;
}
else{
    if (!empty($val)) { 
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user_video (user_uid, video_id, done, created) VALUES ('".$_SESSION['u_uid'] ."', '$id', '$val', '$time');";
        if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } 
        else {
            echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
        }
    }
}
$conn->close();
```

Comment: Where is this from `$row['done']`?

Comment: Can you show your whole (relevant) code in one block?

Comment: ye there is a problem with $row['done']... iv check to update value when data in that row is lees than 100, but always updating it...

Comment: You're never assigning a value to `$row['done']`. Perhaps you need `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either didn't post the full code, or your php is trowing the error message `undefined index 'done'` since you never actually access the values from your `SELECT` query.

The code should look like this:

```
<?php
....
if($resultCheck>0){
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ //Fetch data from the SELECT query
        if ($row['done']< $val) {
            $sql = "UPDATE user_video SET obejrzane='$val' WHERE video_id = '$id' AND user_uid='".$_SESSION['u_uid'] ."'";
                mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        }
    }
    echo $resultCheck;
}
....
```

Comment: Yes that was it :D  it was so obviously but i forget to add it to my code... Thank a lot for point it on.